# What is the difference between an Activity's "Target" and "To" fields?

Tags: getstream-io

What is the difference between an Activity Feed's  "Target" and "To" fields?

Can I use "Target" and "To" interchangeably? If not then what happens if I do use Target and To interchangeably? How does it impact my data and view?

Also, can I have multiple "Target"s?

Answer (score 2):

The "target" field is just a supplemental field for noting that an activity is meant for another user/list, but it's purely a reference only and the field is optional.

The "to" field will actually send your activity to other feeds, like the CC function of your email client. It's also optional but we'll include an empty list in activities when you fetch a feed.

Comment: Thanks for your revert! However, I am still not sure if I will be losing on some functionality if I do not use "Target" and instead always use "To". Also like "To" can I have multiple "Targets" ?

Comment: You won't lose any functionality by omitting the "target" field and only using the "to" field. To add to the above answer, you might consider that the "target" field may be used to store data that's used by your system while the "to" field is used to instruct the Stream API on how to behave.

Comment: Yes, you could have an array as the value for targets, it's an optional field which just has to be meaningful to your application. As @DwightGunning mentioned, the target field doesn't affect how Stream handles your activity to send to others, only the To field does.